# iOS App Hosting, Servers, PHP, JSON? I'm Lost

Tags: php, ios, iphone, json, hosting

I'm learning xCode at the moment and in the process of finishing my app design on the story board.

I want my app to allow users to be able to post their addresses and then letting other users see the addresses on the MapView if the locations are near their houses.

Basically want users to submit data to the servers and then letting that string be avaliable to all app users. I've read about JSON, PHP, hosting, but I'm really not sure where to start from.

I want something like this and then a map view. I'm just not sure where to start from. I really wanna start from the very basics, can someone help me out? Currently I'm using Parse for the sign in and login in credentials and that works. I wanna be able to use an API that transfers the address code to long and latitude aswell.

How I want it to look (just the near me list and maps):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNbtF.png]

Answer (score 0):

You kan use 
    NSURLConnection 
To call you php Script on a normale http Call.

Than you have

```
NSJSONSerialization
```

To Parse your Data.
After this you have a 
     NSDictanary

To work you Data.

Sorry i Write for a Germany iPhone